# Speech-To-Text api error parse the encode of pcm file by AudioRecorder

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, audio-recording

I use AudioRecord in my application to record voice, then I call the speech-to-text api with Firebase, but it always returns that "encode" is incorrect.

```
 val DEFAULT_AUDIO_SOURCE: Int = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.UNPROCESSED
 val DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE_HZ: Int = 16_000
 val DEFAULT_CHANNEL_CONFIG: Int = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO
 val DEFAULT_AUDIO_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
 val BUFFER_SIZE: Int = 2*AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE_HZ, DEFAULT_CHANNEL_CONFIG, DEFAULT_AUDIO_FORMAT)

 mAudioRecord = AudioRecord(
                    DEFAULT_AUDIO_SOURCE,
                    DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE_HZ,
                    DEFAULT_CHANNEL_CONFIG,
                    DEFAULT_AUDIO_FORMAT,
                    DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
```

```
 val data = ByteArray(file.length().toInt())
 val input = DataInputStream(FileInputStream(file));
 input.read(data);
 input.close();
 val audioContent: String = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
 val resp = 
 mApi.transcribe(FirebaseCloudFunctionsModel.Transcribe("LINEAR16", CloudTranslate.DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE_HZ, Locale.getDefault().toString(), audioContent)).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PCM 16 bit, record the audio in a ShortArray buffer(it's size should be half your buffer size as short is 16 bit or 2 bytes) and convert the buffer to ByteArray using this function:

```
private fun short2byte(sData:ShortArray):ByteArray {
  val shortArrsize = sData.size
  val bytes = ByteArray(shortArrsize * 2)
  for (i in 0 until shortArrsize)
  {
    bytes[i * 2] = (sData[i] and 0x00FF).toByte()
    bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (sData[i] shr 8).toByte()
    sData[i] = 0
  }
  return bytes
}
```

Google Cloud API uses URL safe Base64 encoding so add it as one of the flags to encodeString function.

```
 val audioContent: String = Base64.encodeToString(data,  Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Instead of writing the audio to a file, you could directly write it to a ByteArrayOutputStream in memory if the audio is small in size.